# How can I create an iCal alarm that doesn't get synced to all my computers?

Tags: ical

I want to run an Automator script every three weeks that sends an email. I know how to create an alarm in iCal to run the automator script that sends the email. The problem is that the iCal event gets synced to all three of my Macs and they all try to run the script. The script only exists on one of the computers so I get error messages on the other two.

How can I create an event in iCal that doesn't get synced to all my Macs?

Comment: You can create many calendars in iCal, and sync only the ones you choose to other devices.  So create a calendar to contain these alarms.

Comment: Can we assume your calendars are being synced via iCloud?

Comment: @Stu They're still being synced via MobileMe. I'm holding off on switching to iCloud until Bare Bones gets Yojimbo working with it.

Comment: @GEdgar That looks like it will work. It had been so long since I created a calendar I forgot that I could create one that was only on my Mac. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create many calendars in iCal, and sync only the ones you choose to other devices. So create a calendar to contain these alarms.